# Grouping items and expand branches in D3 Org Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Good day, I'm relatively new using D3. I have created a Org Chart using D3 and JQuery/Javascript.

```
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-org-chart@2"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-flextree@2.1.2/build/d3-flextree.js"></script>
```

However, I am trying to figure out how can I open my chart with all the branches expanded by default.  Also, because there are so many people in our group, is there a way to group items in a single node based on office and/or division?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per source code of the d3-org, you will have to use chart.expandAll(); where chart is your created chart. There are other methods like collapseAll, downloadImage, exportSVG etc. You can refer this file https://github.com/bumbeishvili/org-chart/blob/master/src/d3-org-chart.js  to find out which method you want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much this was definitely helpful with the collapseAll and expandAll functionality. Now I need to figure out grouping. However, will give you full credit with your answer. Not sure how I missed this because I've been to that link before.  Thanks again!

Comment: I can think of doing groupBy in two ways, transform the data by grouping before rendering the chart. or you can use removeNode and AddNode apis by removing a subtree of a division/office(removing the root of subtree will work) and adding a single node in place of that. Third way would be to extend this library to add a new function. similar to compact ones.